# Applying training-set on actual data using weka KnowledgeFlow environment

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, training-data

After going through many tutorials on youtube, could not find an answer...

I have two arff files, one with the actual test results, class is numeric 0-48, 
and the other with a '?' as the class.

I've used 10 fold cross validation REPtree and got a reasonably low error.

My problem is that I don't understand how to use weka to apply this training set on the "unpredicted" data that I have. 
The training set consists of users that answered an online survey, and the other file is users who did not answer the survey.

Here is a screenshot of the actual set up I have.
[image]

Thank you very much!!